# How to use a custom OperationId without ending up with memory leaks and it being ignored by Application Insights?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

My question is:

What is the correct/better way to inject a custom Correlation/Operation Id in my scenario, which doesn't result in memory leaks and is correctly used and displayed on the Azure Portal?

And here are the specific details of my scenario:

I have a Azure Worker Role that is constantly dequeueing messages from an Azure queue and doing processing. The message contains a Correlation Id (Operation Id) and Operation Name, which I want to be used for all telemetry collected and pushed through Application Insights during the processing work for that message.

The way this is currently implemented is through a custom `ITelemetryInitializer`, which looks something like this:

```
public class MiTelemetryInitialiser : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly ILoggingContext _context;

    public MiTelemetryInitialiser(ILoggingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Operation.Id) && _context != null)
        {
            telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = _context.OperationId;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_context.OperationName))
                telemetry.Context.Operation.Name = _context.OperationName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then my worker role processing loop look something like this (si:

```
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    // 1. Get message from the queue
    // 2. Extract operation name and Correlation Id from the message
    TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

    var loggingContext = //new logging context with operation name and correlation id
    config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MiTelemetryInitialiser(loggingContext));
    TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);        

    // do work

    client.Flush();
}
```

I am using this `TelemetryChannel`:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
```

There are two issues:

1. Memory leak (significant) - I am guessing due to the way the `ServerTelemetryChannel` is implemented (unfortunately unlike most of the .NET SDK - this channel is not open source) and due to the tight loop?
2. Even though `client.TrackRequest()` is pushing my custom Correlation Id (verified using Fiddler) - Application Insights is overwriting it on the Azure Portal and is displaying its own Operation Id rather than mine. Other telemetry during the request has the correct OperationId which I have set.

Here is a photo of the memory leak after running the loop for ~10 minutes (grows to 1GB+ after a while):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the memory leak problem - we found the root cause and we will fix it in the next version. However in your code example we recommend to not create a new channel every time and instead reuse the same channel. It will allow better batching and less memory overhead:

```
TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

var loggingContext = //new logging context with operation name and correlation id
config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MiTelemetryInitialiser(loggingContext));

while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    // 1. Get message from the queue
    // 2. Extract operation name and Correlation Id from the message
    TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);        

    // do work

    client.Flush();
}
```

Or just use this:

```
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    // 1. Get message from the queue
    // 2. Extract operation name and Correlation Id from the message
    TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();        

    // do work

    client.Flush();
}
```

and add your telemetry initializer into `ApplicationInsigths.config`:

```
<Add Type="Namespace.MiTelemetryInitialiser , AssemblyName" />
```

See also [my blog post](http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/) on how you can add telemetry initializer to the global singleton configuration:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MiTelemetryInitialiser());
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I can't move the `TelemetryInitializers` setup out of the `while` loop, because my OperationId comes from the message in the queue, so in order to have dependency telemetry set with the correct OperationId I have to inject the initializer after I have the OperationId?

Comment: Also, is there a bug somewhere I can track to know when the memory leak is fixed and if it makes it in the release?

Comment: You need to change your telemetry initializer so it gets contexts in Initialize method rather that creating one per each operation. TelemetryClient and TelementryConfiguration are not intended to be created on each operation. Even with memory leak fix there will be a significant performance hit because each time we need to parse configuration file and recreate a channel. Bug fix should come out with Web SDK 2.0-beta2 in ~3 weeks. Bug fix will be done on the github (We are moving channel there right now: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/38)

Comment: @AnastasiaBaranchenkova Thanks for the reply! Makes sense. (For the record and people who read the comments - the pull request with the server channel is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/41 )

Answer (score 2):

For the operation id problem - In recent versions, specifically for request telemetry, to avoid confusion between `RequestTelemetry.ID` and `TelemetryContext.Operation.ID` (from UI perspective), we initialize `TelemetryContext.Operation.ID` and assign the same to the `RequestTelemetry.ID` as soon as the request telemetry is created. See [example at github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/bfeab153de5c9880fa6ce5195b53c812c912e134/src/Core/Managed/Shared/DataContracts/RequestTelemetry.cs#L39). The best way to address this problem of assigning custom operation id is to forcibly assign your operation id, removing `string.IsNullOrEmpty` check.